# Idiomatic Scala List Comprehension - first item that matches

Tags: java, scala, list-comprehension, idioms

Folks,
  I've been writing some code in Scala lately to teach myself the language and in some recent experiments, I've used [an NLP library to produce a set of part-of-speech tagged words](http://www.kotancode.com/2012/02/15/scalamud-scala-java-nlp/) from a user's input.

I want to write a function that gives me the first verb in the sentence. If there are no verbs, then I want to assume that the first word in the set is the verb (e.g. if the player just typed "who" or "uptime" , those are considered verbs by my game).

The following is a block of code so ugly only a mother could love, and it stinks of imperative programming and I want to refactor it into something more like idiomatic Scala, ideally something that doesn't have a single "if" statement in it.

```
def firstVerb = {
    if (words.size == 1)
        words.head.value
    else {
        val outWords = words.filter( word => word.pos == Verb)
        if (outWords == Set.empty) 
            words.head.value
        else
            outWords.head.value 
    }
}
```

The "words" variable is of type ListBuffer[EnrichedWord], where EnrichedWord is my class that contains a part of speech (pos, contains case objects like Verb, Noun, etc) and the original word (value).

Any guidance you Scala geniuses can provide in refactoring this butt-ugly code would be fantastic.

Comment: "...only a mother could love."

Comment: ...only a mother could love." Best phrase I have read today!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This additionally handles the case when `words` is empty, try it:

```
words.find(_.pos == Verb).orElse(words.headOption).map(_.value).getOrElse("")
```

If you are sure `words` will never be an empty `Set`, this one is simpler:

```
words.find(_.pos == Verb).getOrElse(words.head).value
```

BTW if you are using `HashSet` the notion of some element being first doesn't really make sense. If each element represents a word in a sentece, it should have been a `List` or a `Seq`.

Comment: Tried your first option against a ListBuffer (you're right, Set makes no sense here) and got:  error: value map is not a member of ScalaObject with java.io.Serializable   words.find(_.pos == Verb).getOrElse(words.headOption).map(_.value)

Answer (score 2):

The canonical (point-free) version is probably:

```
words find(_.pos == Verb) orElse words.headOption map _.value getOrElse ""
```

Another option is:

```
(words.find(_.pos == Verb) ++ words.take(1)).take(1).map(_.value).mkString
```

Comment: Words can be empty - e.g. the player could have hit enter and submitted a blank command.

Comment: If words is empty, I'm currently just returning "" as the first verb.. I don't like passing nulls around nor do I like making downstream code do Some/None checks.

Comment: That is super clean.. Awesome!

Comment: @KevinHoffman "nor do I like making downstream code do Some/None checks" -- so instead you make it do empty-string/non-empty-string checks??? T_T

Comment: @DanBurton - Indeed.  My code often has stuff equivalent to `s match { case "" => None; case x => Some(x) }` in it just so I _don't_ have to deal with empty strings.  (It actually looks like `s.optOut(_ == "")` due to enriching.)